# Restricting user accessing WebAPI but not SPA website in the same time

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, single-page-application

**Background**: SPA website written in the latest Angular with the ASP.NET WebAPI backend.

**Requirement:** One of our requirements is to expose the WebAPI to the public, and our customer asked us to restrict certain users from accessing our WebAPI but in the same time keeping the full access to the website.

**Possible solutions:** On of our ideas was to check if the origin IP address is different that the website IP address, but we were not sure if this cannot be hacked using the HTTP headers. Another idea was to send different "client_id" in the HTTP request, but again, this can be hacked by the user.

Do you have any better ideas or practices we can use to achieve our final goal?

Comment: Isn't what [**CORS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is made for  ?

Comment: But then you have to have a white or black list of IP addresses that can connect or not, which will not be possible to maintain.

Comment: Well that's kind of the purpose ... How are you supposed to check if the IP is authorized  ?

Comment: Each user belongs to an organisation and we set a flag on organisation level to control if a user can access the API or not. The idea is we check that only when the origin IP address is not the origin IP address of the website, so we know that someone is trying to connect from external source.

Comment: Do you have a single server for both back-end and front-end ?

Comment: Yes. It is a single server.

Comment: Well then, why don't you simply ask for a token or an API key in your back-end ?

Comment: We already do that for every user that is trying to log in to the website. We issue the token which is then used for allowing other requests to go through. How that can help to resolve the original issue?

Comment: Well you don't want white/black listing, so the other solution is tokens or API keys.

Comment: If we use Api Key we have to set it up in the HTTP header level, which will be visible in each request. A user can hack this manually to provide a different key or share they key with others.

Comment: Same thing happens with tokens you know ...